# svelte slider not rendering

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3, svelte-component

dears,
I create a simple slider, but i have a problem in rendering the images, mor information:
i have slider.svelte, app.svelte, index.html.

In `slider.svelte` it has the process of creating the body of the slider with the dots, the code will be like this:

```html
<script lang="ts">
.
.//code
.
</script>

<!-- slider body  -->
<div class="carousel">
  <div
    class="slides"
    bind:this={siema}
    on:mouseenter={pause}
    on:mouseleave={resume}
  >
    <slot />
  </div>
  <div class="indexer">
    {#if haveDots}
      <ul>
        {#each { length: totalDots } as _, i}
          <li
            on:click={() => go(i * currentPerPage)}
            class={isDotActive(currentIndex, i) ? "active" : ""}
          />
        {/each}
      </ul>
    {/if}
  </div>
</div>
```

In `app.svelte`:

```html
<svelte:options tag="app-slider" />
<script lang="ts">
import Sliders from "./lib/Slider.svelte";
.
.//code
.
</script>
<Sliders>
 {#each sliderData["slides"] as slider}
     <a href={slider["lnk"]}>
       <img alt="" src={slider["img"]} />
     </a>
  {/each}
</Sliders>
```

In `index.html` it has:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Vite + Svelte + TS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <app-slider></app-slider>
        <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using custom components when I disable it the slider work when I enable it the part in `<slot />` not rendering at all

I tried to use custom component for the `slot` tag it didn't work

Comment: You mean when you compile it as custom element it just stops working? But it works fine when you compile it the default way as svelte component?

Comment: I would recommend *not* using custom elements unless maybe you are distributing your code as a library to be used by other code (for compatibility with pure HTML). Even then it probably is not worth it unless you have a valid business case for it.

Comment: Why is the question tagged SvelteKit? It does not look like you are using it.